# Как прогнать файл через Beautiful Soup один раз и сохранить сделанные изменения в разные файлы максимально быстро

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup, bs4

Необходимо прогнать файл(потенциально не один) через ***Beautiful Soup*** один раз, а дальше использовать его копии(или иной способ) для работы(изменение и последующее сохранение копий).

В файле несколько таблиц, одна из которых содержит несколько тыс. строк и с десяток полей.

Если использовать **copy.copy()** то выходит около 2.5-4 секунд. Что считаю совсем не быстро.
Разбирать файл каждый раз, получается быстрее.

Подскажите, как можно максимально быстро выполнить задачу!? Может быть возможно применить иной подход!?

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import bs4
import copy

def test(soup:bs4):
    ''' Разбор файла и получение необходимых данных. Вернуть Dict'''

    # Простой разбор и получение данных из "soup"

    data = {'soup':soup, 'и':'т.д.'}

    return data
   
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Открыть файл
    with open(r'C:/index.html', 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
        file = f.read()
    
    # Прогон файла через Beautiful Soup один раз
    soup = bs(file, 'lxml')

    # Разобрать и получить необходимые данные из файла
    preparing_data = test(soup)

    N = 10
    
    # На каждой итерации взять исходник "soup"
    # произвести какие-то действия и сохранить в отдельные файл(ы).
    for i in range(N):
        soup = copy.copy(preparing_data['soup']) # Сильно медленно.

        # Куча каких-то действия с "soup", в том числе изменение
        # и последующее сохранение в отдельный файл.
        # Например добавление/удаление тегов, стилей и др.
```

Comment: `multiprocessing.Pool()` не рассматривали?

Comment: @Namerek нет, не рассматривал. Я не использовал его раньше, поэтому даже не очень представляю как его прикрутить

Comment: @Namerek и как это будет работать если vCPU = 1